# Wordpress редактор на странице опций темы не сохраняет введенные данные после отправки данных

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Вот сам код на странице настроек " Опции темы "

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
    <?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
    <?php
      $settings = array(
        'textarea_name' =>  'theme_settings[editor]',
        'editor_class'  =>  'my_redactor commons',
        'dfw'       =>  true,
        'quicktags' =>  false
      );
      wp_editor( '', 'theme_settings', $settings );
    ?>
       <input name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Сохранить" type="submit">
 </form>
```

Таким образом выводится на сайте введенные данные

```
<?php echo $options['editor'] ?>
```

Но после отправки данных формы в админке на странице опций темы редактор снова пустой. То есть в админке я не вижу что было введено в редактор ранее и что сейчас есть на сайте.
Как сделать так чтобы сохранялись данные в редакторе?

Comment: А кто должен сохранять настройки? Святой дух? get_option() вижу, а где update_option()? Ну и вообще, всё неправильно. Почитайте на русском, как надо делать страницу настроек: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html

Comment: Создавал страницу настроек по этой статье  http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-sozdat-stranicu-nastroek-temy-bez-plagina-wordpress.html  и решил попробовать WP редактор туда вставить.

Comment: Есть 2 надёжных источника - Codex и kama